# left-to-right itemize in multicols environment

Tags: lists, itemize, multicol

I have this code that uses the multicols environment to split a list on multiple columns:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
    \item List1ItemA
    \item List1ItemB
    \item List1ItemC
    \item List1ItemD
    \item List1ItemE
    \item List1ItemF
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
    \item List2ItemA
    \item List2ItemB
    \item List2ItemC
    \item List2ItemD
    \item List2ItemE
    \item List2ItemF
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

I get this output:

[image: reality]

But I want a left-to-right (horizontal) order. Like this:

[image: expectation]

Comment: Give the `tasks` package a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `multicols` environment is no real demand, the `tasks` environment provides left to right alignment of the individual items.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\task E
\task F
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```