# How to place enumerations in rows, not columns in ConTeXt?

Tags: enumerate, context, columns

Similar to the LaTeX answer in [left-to-right itemize in multicols environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288182/left-to-right-itemize-in-multicols-environment), in which `\usepackage{tasks}` is used, I want to place itemizations in rows, like this, but need a ConTeXt solution:

```
a. test    b. test    c. test    d. test
e. test    d. test    f. test    g. test
h. test    i. test    j. test    k. test
```

I have experimented with lots of code, and the closest I can get is this, but the items appear in order down the columns, not in rows:

```
\starttest
    \startitemize[a,columns,five,packed,broad]
        \dorecurse{15}{\item test\endgraf}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

How do I create enumerated rows of items, lined up in columns, in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked a [very similar question](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086898.html) on the list some time ago. This could be what you look for, or at least put you in the right direction:

```
\starttext
    \startitemize[a,horizontal,five,packed,broad]
        \dorecurse{15}{\startitem test\stopitem}
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Note that this will work only with `\startitem… \stopitem`, not with `\item`